# Transparent CSS hexagon with non-tranparent text without rendering problems in android

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, browser

I'm trying to find a solution for displaying a transparent hexagon created with CSS and non-transparent text on top of it without having rendering issues in android or other browsers.

I want to end up with something like this, without using `svg` or `png`.

[image: What I'm trying to get]

All I'm ending up with is either having a transparent hexagon and transparent text or a hexagon with a weird looking transparent effect.

Everything I tried for now:

1. https://jtauber.github.io/articles/css-hexagon.html
   **Problem**: Rendering issues in android and chrome. When displayed on my phone or chrome responsive view the hexagon have these thin lines.
   [image]
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17316755/5826532
   **Problem**: I tried the code for the first hexagon shown in the answer and it has the same rendering issues in android. The second hexagon code displayed with `rgba()` creates a weird looking hexagon, where you see the barebone of the hexagon (as you can see in the image below). By using `opacity` the text is going to be transparent too.
   Here is a fiddle for weird looking hexagon https://jsfiddle.net/8kmjLL7x/
   [image: Weird looking transparent hexagon]

Comment: mix-blend-mode with full color could be an hint https://jsfiddle.net/8kmjLL7x/1/

Comment: @GCyrillus did you try this in your fiddle? Because the hexagons are not transparent.

Comment: you need to test this with chrome or firefox, it is not yet avalaible for IE ( see http://canisue.com  (i usually do not waste time to post not working fiddle , but in comments i do not mind to post CSS that is not yet avalaible everywhere ... to avoid hey, it is not working ;) another example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENqqaE

Comment: This is a screenshot from my android phone : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixSet.jpg if you still wonder if it worked ;)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I think `mix-blend-mode` won't do the job correctly. Especially when the background image changes, the blend can get really weird looking. I think I have to solve this by using `svg` or `png` instead, until the rendering issues in android will be fixed.